# How can I connect multiple 24LC04B's on the same I2C

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to store some data on a EEPROM, but unfortunately I cannot fit it into a single 24LC04B, therefor I want to connect another 24LC04B to the I2C line to compensate for the lack of memory.

The 24LC04B has only two actual addresses/pages (0x50, 0x51), but the problem is that it's also using another 6 addresses/pages as a mirror of the first two for some reason..:

**i2cdetect -y 1**

```
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
 00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

For 24LC128, I can change the I2C address of the EEPROM by connecting A0, A1 and A2 pins to the VCC pin, which gives me an address selection in a range of 0x50 to 0x57.

For the 24LC04B this seems to have no effect and I cannot find any information on how to disable the address mirroring ether. Even if the 24LC128 was big enough, I still can't add it to the I2C line, because 24LC04B is using up all the address space with the mirrored addresses..

Is there a way to connect two 24LC04B's on the same I2C line? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a 8K I2C Serial EEPROM? (24AA08/24LC08B)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat 04B and 128 were the only ones I had by hand, but after posting this I realized that the 24LC128 actually has plenty of memory (128 Kbit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet I checked (Microchip) explicitly states that the A0-A2 pins are *not connected*, hence there is no way to have more than one such chip on a pure I2C bus.

You could restore to tricks like using two separate (bit banged?) I2C busses - the I2C protocol is not that complex - or swithing one or both of the lines, using some other GPIO pin. That could be as simple as a few resistors and maybe a diode, or as complex as using a dedicated IC.